# Python simple webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

This is a customize code like automate the boring stuff web scraping chapter 11. but i can't seem to get it to work so i change it a little. but i still do get en empty list back in return.

i run this script in the cmd, for example the title of the script which is allsearch.py , it will be allsearch.py something that you want to search in the cmd.

```
import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4

print('Searching...')    # display text while downloading the search result page
res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))

try:
    res.raise_for_status()  
except Exception as Ex:
    print(f'Error as occur: {Ex}')

if res.status_code == 200:
    print('Success')
else:
    print('Not Found')

# Retrieve top search result links.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
# Open a browser tab for each result.
linkElems = soup.select('a href')
print(linkElems)

#Opening the searches
numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    urlToOpen = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + linkElems[i].get('href')
    print('Opening', urlToOpen)
    webbrowser.open(urlToOpen)
```

i can't seem to find the problem here.

Comment: How are you executing this script? Please add the script call to the question.

Comment: Have you tried `print(res.text)`? Knowing Google, they probably detect `requests` and don't show you any search results you could scrape.

Comment: yes , res.text is fine as it succesfully got the data . its just i want to automate the opening tabs in the browser for what i type in. Its the link Elems that have a empty list when i print it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your line:

```
linkElems = soup.select('a href')
```

`a` is the container type, when you type it like that, it is looking for `a href` labeled containers--there are none.

`href` is an *attribute* and if you want to use it, you need to provide a value for it.  There are plenty of examples in bs4 dox.

try:

```
linkElems = soup.select('a')
```

and you will get a fruitful response.

Comment: This actually opened up the tabs in the browser but its not actually what i want it to open , do you know anywaysto open up the links in google . for example , if i type in keyboard it will automatically opened up the keyboard links in google automatically.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "open the links in Google"  If you "open a link" it is going to open that web page, just like your code is doing in the last part.  Do you mean "show the search results" in one page as if you typed in a google search and you want to see a results page?

Comment: yep, i want to open up all the search result search by the browser with the word you key in the cmd

Comment: It still isn't clear what you mean by "open up all the search result" because that's what your code is doing...  opens up all results in different tabs.  If you just want to *show* the result of the search itself, then you don't need to scrape anything.  You are already constructing the search command in the 4th line of your code...just open that link after constructed.

Comment: yea , i get what you mean but if you try it its not actually opening up th search result links its just opening up some rnadom tbas that have the keyword you key in

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add headers to access google results, so start with something like:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]), headers=headers)
```

Then, for `linkElems`:

```
linkElems = soup.select("div.r a[href]")
```

This translates to find all `a` tags that have a `href`, located under `div` with `class='r'`. This is to fetch just `a[href]` from results and not from other places in the page.

To open the `href` links, in your last loop just do a:

```
urlToOpen = linkElems[i].get('href')
#...
```

,as `href` already stores the full url.

Comment: i understand the linkelems part, but i am not sure what the headers variable do, can you explain alittle more thanks.

Comment: Do a `print(soup.text)` without headers, then do it again with headers. You will see they are different. That's because google picks up that it's a script executing the request and will not show return the search results. Same to what @AKX said.